# C# returning an XML element with ancestors and self, but no other children

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml doc layout like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document name="document name">
    <DataSet name="dataset 1">
        <Dimension name="dimension 1">
            <Metric name="metric 1">
                <Data value="1">
                <Data value="2">
                <Data value="3">
            </Metric>
            <Metric name="metric 2">
                <Data value="4">
                <Data value="5">
                <Data value="6">
            </Metric>
        </Dimension>
        <Dimension name="dimension 2">
            <Metric name="metric 3">
                <Data value="6">
                <Data value="7">
                <Data value="8">
            </Metric>
            <Metric name="metric 4">
                <Data value="9">
                <Data value="10">
                <Data value="11">
            </Metric>
        </Dimension>
    </DataSet>
</Document>
```

I am attempting to split the Metrics out with their ancestors but not with their siblings. For example I want a file to look like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document name="document name">
    <DataSet name="dataset 1">
        <Dimension name="dimension 1">
            <Metric name="metric 1">
                <Data value="1">
                <Data value="2">
                <Data value="3">
            </Metric>
        </Dimension>
    </DataSet>
</Document>
```

and file 2 to look like ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Document name="document name">
        <DataSet name="dataset 1">
            <Dimension name="dimension 1">
                <Metric name="metric 2">
                    <Data value="4">
                    <Data value="5">
                    <Data value="6">
                </Metric>
            </Dimension>
        </DataSet>
    </Document>
```

My attempt to solve this was to create a method that would accept an xmlfile, outputDirectory, elementName, attributeName, and attributeValue.

This would allow me to search the document for a specific metric and pull it out into its own file with its entire tree, but not with it's siblings.

at the top of my method i have...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

IEnumerable<XElement> elementsInPath = doc.Descendants()
                                        .Elements(elementName)
                                        .Where(p => p.Attribute(attributeName).Value.Contains(attributeValue))
                                        .AncestorsAndSelf()
                                        .InDocumentOrder()
                                        .ToList();
```

However when I iterate through the elementsInPath The output gives all of the parents of the matched "Metric" with each parent return all of its children, and the only child i want present is the one that was matched by the input params.

Any help would be appreciated. Just for reference I save the files using the following snippet

```
                int i = 1;
                foreach (XElement element in elementsInPath)
                {
                    XDocument tmpDoc = new XDocument();
                    tmpDoc.Add(element);
                    tmpDoc.Save(outputDirectory + elementName + "_" + i + ".xml");
                    i++;
                }
```

Also to note, If I use the following code I get the exact metrics I am looking for, but i need to encapsulate them within their parents.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsInPath = doc.Descendants(elementName)
                                                        .Where(p => p.Attribute(attributeName).Value.Contains(attributeValue))
                                                        .InDocumentOrder()
                                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: I was about to ask what do you get without `.AncestorsAndSelf()` part, but you were visionary :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're really building a new document for each `Metric` element.  The most straightforward way to do this would be:

```
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Descendants("Metric"))
{
    XElement newDoc =
        new XElement("Document",
            new XAttribute(doc.Root.Attribute("name")), 
            new XElement("DataSet", 
                new XAttribute(el.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name")),
                new XElement("Dimension", 
                    new XAttribute(el.Parent.Attribute("name")), 
                    el)
                )
            )
        );
    newDoc.Save(el.Attribute("name").Value.Replace(" ", "_") + ".xml");
}
```

This hopefully illustrates how the dynamic version of this would work - iterate through the ancestors and create new elements based on them:

```
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Descendants("Metric"))
{
    XElement newDoc = el;
    foreach(XElement nextParent in el.Ancestors()) // iterate through ancestors
    {
        //rewrap in ancestor node name/attributes
        newDoc = new XElement(nextParent.Name, nextParent.Attributes(), newDoc);
    }

    newDoc.Save(el.Attribute("name").Value.Replace(" ", "_") + ".xml");
}
```

Just using the `Ancestors()` functionality won't work, because when you tried to add them it would also add their children (the siblings of the element you're trying to split on).

Comment: Yes my node names will be dynamic. I have a form that will take in the elementName to search / split the document by. So I need a way to programmatically get all of the parents of the element "metric". I figured I could retrieve the element, and then keep asking for its parents in a recursive loop, but I wouldn't know how to build the file back up.

Comment: thanks! That works like a charm. I see now that you build a new parent element using the name and attribute from the original doc, so that no children comes with it.

Comment: Right - that's basically what I did in the "static" version, but now I have i tset to just get all attributes and the name from the parent element.